# How to run a plug for a connection after the request is sent in Elixir/Phoenix?

Tags: logging, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am writing an Phoenix project in Elixir and I want to implement custom logging for routes.

I've written a plug that uses `Conn.register_before_send` like the default plug does (https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/logger.ex) to calculate query time, but when I execute it, it doesn't provide me some data that I need to log and is not there yet before the response is sent, like `Content-Length` response header for instance.

So, the question: is there a way I can implement the same thing, but executing the logging after the request is sent instead of before?